# how to get the normal print statement execution when using stdout=subprocess.PIPE during subprocess call in python

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I am starting a `subprocess` in python through this command:

```
result = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "/subscript.py"] + parameter,stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
result.wait()
out, err = result.communicate()
for line in out.splitlines():
    print line
```

The problem that I am facing with this approach is that all the `print` statements in `subscript.py` are kind of buffered till the end and are printed on the `terminal` at the end of the execution. So if my `subscript.py` takes about 15 minutes in execution then for 15 minutes the `terminal` does not shows anything and once the `subscript.py` execution ends then all the print statements are printed together. I know this is because of the use of `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and if I remove it then I will get what I want but I cannot remove it as I am using it to get the value  of a variable from the `subscript.py` (I am printing that variable in `subscript.py` and then in parent script I am going through each print to get the print with variable value).

So, what I want is that all the print statements should be printed as they are encountered in the `subscript.py` without any buffering till the end of the execution. Is there a way to do that?

**UPDATE:** I tried to follow [**J.F. Sebastian's method**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715847/python-read-streaming-input-from-subprocess-communicate/17698359#17698359) but I still get the same output. The prints from subprocess are buffered and once the subprocess ends then they are printed to the terminal. The updated code I have is:

```
result = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "/subscript.py"] + parameter,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,bufsize=1)

with result.stdout:
        for line in iter(result.stdout.readline, b''):
            print line,
result.wait()
```

Comment: Have you tried using `result.stdout.readline`? You can wrap it in `iter()` and you should be able to iterate through the stdout lines as they are generated.

Comment: @russdot No I haven't tried that. At which point  should I do that? I mean should i do it before `result.wait()` or after it?

Comment: @russdot can you show how to wrap it in `iter()` and where should I place it in my code?

Comment: Check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects): `wait()` waits until the child process terminates, and should not be used with `stdout=PIPE`. Instead, try removing calls to `wait()` and `communicate()` and instead try:
`for line in iter(result.stdout.readline):
    print line`

Comment: @russdot the reason I am using `wait()` is so that my parent script waits for the subprocess to finish before moving ahead with next parts of the code. The code that I have posted above is just a small part of the parent script. The parts after the above code depend on the successful execution of above script so I have to wait till the above script finishes

Comment: The purpose of `iter()` is that it will iterate through the `stdout` lines until EOF is reached. So the `for line in iter()` loop should keep going until the output from the subprocess has been exhausted. To be honest I haven't had a chance to test the code, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82841/discussion-between-russdot-and-user2966197).

Comment: @russdot I executed the above and got `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable error at for line in iter(result.stdout.readline):`

Comment: Maybe `sys.stdout.flush()` somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

The answer that you've linked prints anything only after the stdout buffer is flushed in the child as it is explicitly said in [the answer itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279).

Use [`-u` parameter](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u), to unbuffer stdout in the Python child process:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

result = Popen([sys.executable, '-u', '/path/to/subscript.py'] + parameters, 
               stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)
with result.stdout:
    for line in iter(result.stdout.readline, b''):
        print line,
result.wait()
```